# Fail to return a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function in C, which returns the pointer to an array. Each element of this array is a pointer to the initialized structure, and in each structure there's also a pointer to an array.

```
struct queueRecord;
typedef struct queueRecord* queue;

queue createQueue(int maxSize){
    queue newQueue = malloc(sizeof(struct queueRecord));
    newQueue->array = malloc(sizeof(int)*maxSize);
    newQueue->capacity=maxSize;
    newQueue->front=0;
    newQueue->rear=0;
    return newQueue;
}
```

**This just works fine as well as in the following function:**

```
queue* initQArr(int maxSize){
    queue arr[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        arr[i]=createQueue(maxSize);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

**when I pass the parameter 10 in it and set a breakpoint at return, everything seems good**
(excuse me I can't post images, the debug information is like following):

```
arr(queue[10])
 [0]=(queue)0x100105480
   capacity=(int)10
   size=(int)0
   front=(int)0
   rear=(int)0
   array=(int*)0x1001054a0
 [1]=(queue)0x1001054d0
 ...
 ...
 [9]=(queue)0x100105760
```

**However!When I invoke this function and return to a new array, I got an array with only 5 elements:**

```
queue *digitsQArr = initQArr(length);
int digit = 0;
```

(debug information as following):

```
digitQArr = (queue*)0x7fff5fbff6d0
    *digitsArr=(queue)0x100105480
        capacity=(int)10
        size=(int)0
        front=(int)0
        rear=(int)0
        array=(int*)0x1001054a0
    [1]=(queue)0x1001054d0
    ...
    ...
    [4]=(queue)0x1001055d0
```

Comment: You are returning an array that goes out of scope when the function initQArr finishes execution. You must dynamically allocate memory to "arr" and return that.

Comment: In case you're wondering why there appeared to be five valid elements, [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) is directly related. And fyi, [**the selected answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/1322972) is *stellar*.

Comment: Or declare it as `static`. E.g. `static queue arr[10];`

Comment: @itachi I try to declare _arr_ as `queue* arr=malloc(sizeof(struct queueRecord)*10)`, then _arr_ also has only 5 elements when in the function. There must be something wrong when I allocate the memory...

Comment: @itachi hey you are right! It works after dynamically allocate memory to `arr`. What is confusing is that only 5 of them are displayed in debug mode in XCODE... Anyway, the program works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `initQArr`, you return the address of a local variable, `arr`:

```
queue* initQArr(int maxSize){
    queue arr[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        arr[i]=createQueue(maxSize);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The returned pointer will point to the local array `arr`, which is no longer valid once the function returns. You could follow the example of `createQueue` and allocate memory on the heap:

```
queue* initQArr(int maxSize){
    queue *arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(*arr));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        arr[i]=createQueue(maxSize);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

After returning, the pointer `arr` is still valid, because it points to memory on the heap. You should `free` such memory after using it, like the queue pointers allocated in `createQueue`.

Comment: But when I use `queue *arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(*arr));` ,I got an `arr` with only 5 valid elements even in the function `initQArr`

Comment: How do you check this? Do you print the array contents and get weird pointers? What do you mean with "valid" element?

Comment: **It works** after I dynamically allocate the memory! However, only 5 elements are displayed in the debug window when I debug in XCODE, so weird...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xcode or its debugger, but because C arrays don't know about their size, the debugger can't either. In gdb (which appears to be one of the debuggers supported by Xcode), you'd have to print `p *arr@10`, where the number after the `@` is how many entries you want to print.